# Farsi characters not displaying in Android app

Tags: android

I am creating stream based farsi application for android 3.0. It is displaying 'squares' at the places of characters `گ ڪ ڙ ا`

How can I add support for farsi?

Answer (score 2):

It means that fonts your device uses do not support farsi characters (hence `squares`). You need to find better font and use it in your application (see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Typeface.html docs)

Answer (score 1):

you need to make use of **Typeface** to support additional fonts.

create a new folder called **assets**(if it doesnot exists). create a new folder in it called **fonts**(just for your simplicity)

download the 'farsi' fonts from the internet and copy it in the fonts folder.

in your class file `create a String to the path of the font.`
and use this code

```
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), fontPath);
    txt1.setTypeface(tf);
```

Edit: some fonts may support in one mobile and in other it might not.
for example hindi font is supported in my xperia but not in my friends S2.

Answer (score 0):

First Download the ttf files from any one of the links,

http://www.neda.net.ir/downloads/fonts/persian.ttf

http://alefba.us/wp-content/plugins/download-monitor/download.php?id=farsifonts-0.4.zip

```
 copy the ttf file into assets folder in your project,,
```

first select the Languge code as Farsi in code on clicking button

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Locale myLocale = new Locale("fa"); 
            Resources res = getResources(); 
            DisplayMetrics dispmetrics = res.getDisplayMetrics(); 
            Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration(); 
            conf.locale = myLocale; 
            res.updateConfiguration(conf, dispmetrics);
            String current_locale = getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getDisplayName();
            System.out.println(current_locale);
            Intent refresh = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(refresh);
        }
    });
```

then below ,
              setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

```
              implement this code,,to get the typeFace done

            String current_locale = getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getDisplayName();
    System.out.println("-----"+current_locale);

    if(current_locale.equals("Persian"))
    {

    Typeface font1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "persian.ttf");
    b1.setTypeface(font1);
    }
```

this solution definitely works and the reason that square brackets appears in your phone is due to that **Farsi Unicode is not installed on your Mobile and if u want to install Farsi font your phone must be rooted one**

--Thanks